# Issue setup an asynchronous client callback using the golang implementation of capnp

Tags: go, capnproto

Using the [golang implementation of capnp](https://github.com/capnproto/go-capnp), I would like to build a server that can accept a callback function from the client to be called later by the server. Here is my example.

#### example_schema.capnp

```
using Go = import "/go.capnp";

$Go.package("rpc_example");
$Go.import("rpc_example");

interface ClientCallbackInterface {
    callbackMethod @0 () -> ();
}

interface ServerInterface {
    registerCallback @0 (callback :ClientCallbackInterface);
    invokeCallback @1 ();
}
```

#### example_server.go

```
package main

import (
    "capnproto.org/go/capnp/v3"
    "capnproto.org/go/capnp/v3/rpc"
    "context"
    "example-capnp/rpc_example"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type ServerImpl struct {
    callback rpc_example.ClientCallbackInterface
}

func (s *ServerImpl) RegisterCallback(ctx context.Context, call rpc_example.ServerInterface_registerCallback) error {
    fmt.Println("Server: Registering a callback.")

    params := call.Args()
    cb := params.Callback()
    s.callback = cb

    fmt.Println("Server: Callback registered.")

    // This invocation works
    _, _ = s.callback.CallbackMethod(ctx, nil)
    return nil
}

func (s *ServerImpl) InvokeCallback(_ context.Context, _ rpc_example.ServerInterface_invokeCallback) error {
    fmt.Println("Server: Invoking the callback.")

    // This invocation does not work.
    _, _ = s.callback.CallbackMethod(context.Background(), nil)

    fmt.Println("Server: Callback invoked.")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:2000")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
    }

    server := ServerImpl{}
    client := rpc_example.ServerInterface_ServerToClient(&server)

    rwc, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
    }

    conn := rpc.NewConn(rpc.NewStreamTransport(rwc), &rpc.Options{
        BootstrapClient: capnp.Client(client),
    })

    // Block until the connection terminates.
    select {
    case <-conn.Done():
        client.Release()
    case <-ctx.Done():
        _ = conn.Close()
    }
}
```

#### example_client.go

```
package main

import (
    "capnproto.org/go/capnp/v3/rpc"
    "context"
    "example-capnp/rpc_example"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

type Callback struct{}

func (c Callback) CallbackMethod(_ context.Context, call rpc_example.ClientCallbackInterface_callbackMethod) error {
    fmt.Println("Client: CallbackMethod has been invoked.")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    rwc, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:2000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    conn := rpc.NewConn(rpc.NewStreamTransport(rwc), nil)
    defer conn.Close()

    d := rpc_example.ServerInterface(conn.Bootstrap(ctx))

    // Register callback
    fmt.Println("Client: Registering a callback.")
    callback := Callback{}
    d.RegisterCallback(ctx, func(params rpc_example.ServerInterface_registerCallback_Params) error {
        cb := rpc_example.ClientCallbackInterface_ServerToClient(callback)
        return params.SetCallback(cb)
    })

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

    fmt.Println("Client: Invoking callback.")
    _, release := d.InvokeCallback(ctx, nil)
    defer release()
    fmt.Println("Client: Invoked callback.")

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

}
```

### The issue

The problem that I am facing is that the `ServerImpl.callback` becomes invalid when the scope of the `RegisterCallback` method ends. So the client's callback function can be called in the `RegisterCallback` method but not in the `InvokeCallback` method.

[This conversation](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/issues/591) in capnp's cpp repo suggests that this should be possible.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

I have made this work by calling the `AddRef()` method on the callback passed to the `RegisterCallback` method. I.e. by changing the line `s.callback = cb` to `s.callback = cb.AddRef()` in the `ServerImpl.RegisterCallback` method.

According to the documentation, `AddRef()` creates a new client that points to the same capability. I'm not sure how the clients obtained from the `params.Callback()` and the `AddRef()` are different is such a way that one of them remains valid.